# Error while inserting into database c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

**there is no error just a clarification**

I am trying to insert into a table called "Test" which has one column, a primary key called "id". I am new to using databases in visual studio and think there is something wrong with my insert syntax since all other functions work fine. is the general layout like this?

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES(1)", conn))
```

overall code looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connection =
            "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
            "User Instance=true;" +
            "Integrated Security=true;" +
            "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|HaythamService.mdf;";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES(1)", conn))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.Read();
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the error is??? How is the column defined - is it an identity column as well?

Comment: well there is actually no error, it is not isnerting into database, i am wondering if my insert statement is wrong

Comment: First, if there is no error where you get the `Error while inserting into database` from??. If you just need an explanation, please read [How to: Insert New Records into a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx)

Comment: Also you have both `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `ExecuteReader()`. You just need `ExecuteReader()` if you expect to grab return values from database

Comment: Your code is silently swallowing the exception. Add a message box in the `catch` block or remove it entirely. You'll see what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: swallowing the exception will not help. Remove the try-catch-block and let your application run into the error - then you'll see what the problem is.

Secondly: You're executing the INSERT command using `ExecuteNonQuery` and right after that try to read from it using an `SqlDataReader`? What kind of output do you expect from that?

Probably, if `ID` is a primary key column, that will also be the cause of a primary key violation error, because actually you're executing the same insert twice using the same value - and this is not allowed for a primary key.

To put it short: Create a second command you `ExecuteReader`. The command should read `SELECT * FROM Test`.

Thirdly: Do use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to create your connection string instead of hardcoding it. This will help you against invalid connection strings.